# Replace a name in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm working on a assignment and I need to replace Alice with my name. Here is the program,

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    print(split_alice[i]).replace_alice("Alice","Alex")
```

So I just need help to make the program read the `i` in range part with my name instead of Alice.

Thanks.

Comment: what programming language are you working on??

Comment: You are going to need to post the `split_alice` array and the `replace_alice()` function.  We cannot write that for you, as it would complete your assignment entirely. We are happy to help with an assignment where you are stuck, if you post a solid effort. We're unlikely to give full answers thoguh.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replace()` method on strings..
**Like this**

```py
>>> mystr = 'My name is Alice'
>>> mystr.replace('Alice','Alex')
'My name is Alex'
```

Also, if you have any doubts about anything, you should use `help()`.
Like in your case:

```py
>>> help(type(mystr))
Help on class str in module __builtin__:

class str(basestring)
 |  str(object) -> string
...
...
 |  replace(...)
 |      S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
 |      
 |      Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
 |      old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
 |      given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
 |  
...
...
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
 |      T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T
```

Comment: On behalf of @divoom You can check this out [In Python, how do I find the index of an item given a list containing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/176918/1931274)