# replacing all variations of first/last name

Tags: regex, string, nlp

**Background**

I have the following code that is a variation of the  #[Replace a name in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187137/replace-a-name-in-a-string-in-python)

```
s = "The myth of Johnny Appleseed states that he ate many apple seeds"
s.replace('Johnny Appleseed','***')
```

**Output**

```
'The myth of *** states that he ate many apple seeds'
```

**Problem**

But what if the first and last name contains many variations (non-exhaustive list)

```
#misspellings 
Johnny Applseed
Johny Appleseed
Johnny Applesee

#Letter case 
johnny appleseed
JOHNNY APPLESEED
JoHny ApPleseED
```

**Question**

How do I get the same output as above

```
'The myth of *** states that he ate many apple seeds'
```

If any or all of these variations are present in the first and last name?

Comment: In that case you could account for the characters by making some optional using `?` or use quantifier like `*` for 0+ times or `+` for 1+ times and make the match case insensitive by perhaps using a flag `/i` or set it in the code if possible. For example `\bJohn+y Apple?seed?\b` see https://regex101.com/r/FaJqv6/1

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

If we would know that'd be Johnny, then we would start with an expression similar to:

```
\b[johny]+\b\s+\b[aplsed]+\b
```

If not, we would design a close expression, then we would trade off for the accuracy that we might want.

[Please see the demo for additional info and explanation in here](https://regex101.com/r/fENQxM/1).